# Need to change source code of an installed library

Tags: python-3.x, github

I am using Python3.4. I have installed a certain "itunespy" library from GitHub with pip, to work with iTunes API.
(https://github.com/spaceisstrange/itunespy)

I can now access it from console by

```
import itunespy
```

Except the library is only searching the US store through iTunes Api, whereas I need to access the UK store. I looked into the code and found I only need to change two lines to fix my problem.

Please can you tell me how I can access and change the source code of an already installed library.

Thank you.

Comment: `itunespy.__file__` will show you path to imported module / package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at [source code](https://github.com/spaceisstrange/itunespy/blob/master/itunespy/__init__.py), and:

a) you may obviously change your source code in locally-copied file

b) you may patch these constants in run-time, like adding this type of code to your main:

```
import itunespy
itunespy.base_search_url = "NEW_VALUE"
itunespy.base_lookup_url = "NEW_VALUE"
```

c) library API seems to provide country keyword argument, so you do not have to do any of these hacks mentioned above. Simply do:

```
itunespy.search_track('something', country='UK')
```

With this keyword argument, searches should work as expected without any modifications of source code.

Answer (score 1):

- Fork the repository
- Clone the forked repository
- Make changes and push to your remote (origin, usually)
- You may pip install from your fork

Comment: I'd add something about submitting a pull request to suggest the package author incorporate your changes, since it sounds like this change would be generally useful. Otherwise, there's not much point in forking - you might as well just clone it and edit it locally.

Comment: You PR may have changes to make this configurable. @David The problem by just cloning and editing is, you need to commit and version control the external modules. Else, the change would be lost for future installs.

Comment: One drawback of forking is, you might need to keep your fork updated with the upstream (usually) remote. Else, the changes to the original module would not reflect in your fork.

Comment: re: (2 comments up) Yes, of course you should commit your change, and keep up to date with new upstream changes. But that's equally true whether you fork and clone the fork or just clone the original repository.

Answer (score 0):

you really want to change the sourcecode?
How about just change your implementation?

- inherit from the class
- override/overload their methods with your own
- work with your inherited class and their methods

> pro: if there are changes in the original library you will take them with you when you update (secure-patches etc.) but your overridden/overloaded methods are still the one you use.

otherwise if you really want to change the source code, take a branch from github and change the sourcecode as you need it like mentioned by dolftax